# Get the contents of a tag using preg match all

Tags: php, regex

how can I get the link of this string using preg match all ?

```
<h3 class='post-title entry-title'>
<a href='http://domain.blogspot.com/2011/03/blog-post_111.html'>Test Post</a>
</h3>
```

This is what I did so far

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com');

    $regex_pattern = "/<h3 class=\'post-title entry-title\'>([^`]*?)<\/h3>/";

unset($matches);
preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $string, $matches);


foreach ($matches[0] as $paragraph) {
echo $paragraph;
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe `/href='([^']*)'/gi` helps?

when creating Regular Expressions RegExr is a nice tool. But regular expressions are far to slow. you can get the same effect with a bit more code and the 3 functions: strlen, strpos and substr. That would be one of the fastes versions how to handle this.

Try

```
function between ( $before , $after , $subject )
{
    $subject = $subject;
    $start = strpos ( $subject , $before );
    if ( $start !== false )
    {
        $end = strpos ( $subject , $after , $start );
        if ( $end !== false )
        {
            return substr ( $subject , $start + strlen ( $before ) , $end - ( $start + strlen ( $before ) ) );
        };
    };
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex to parse HTML. Use a DOM parser like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDOcument) instead.

Comment: Hi there CanSpice and thanks for the info. Please can you give me an example on how to convert my code? I updated my post with it in.